# - viewDidLoad infinite loop issue...(iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm attempting to write a multiview app in iOS and really having a bit of a tough time... I've setup a new project and I've got a rootViewController being launched by the appDelegate. In turn, the rootViewController attempts to load and display my first content view, although I seem to have fallen into some kind of infinite loop, I'm hoping someone here may have a hunch as to why...

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
{   
    // Load up new instance of view
    TopLevelViewController *topLevelController = 
    [[TopLevelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopLevelView" bundle:nil];

    // Hand off viewController reference to root controller
    self.topLevelViewController = topLevelController;

    // Display the view
    [self.view insertSubview:topLevelController.view atIndex:0];

    // Release viewController
    [topLevelController release];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Above is my rootViewController viewDidLoad: method, although every time it executes insertSubview, it seems to return to the top and perform the whole thing again. I'm a bit confused as I've based this code almost identically on a tutorial I followed and it ran beautifully...which leads me to think the problem must be elsewhere, although I couldn't possibly think where.

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Your rootViewController isn't of type `TopLevelViewController` by any chance?

Comment: @lxt
No, it's of type RootViewController, although that did cross my mind!

Comment: Why do you think you get an infinite loop? Try to remove [topLevelController release]; line - I don't think you should release controller in that place...

Comment: @Vladimir: He should release it, assuming the `topLevelViewController` property retains it. Otherwise, it will leak.

Comment: ah sorry, indeed missed that property was used, not just simple assignment. Please ignore that comment

Comment: Looking at it closer, I suppose I should have said it looks like infinite recursion rather than an infinite loop.

Comment: Does your `topLevelViewController` inherit from `rootViewController` by any chance?

Comment: Is root vc from nib or created programmatically? I susspect you don't have self.view, but that would cause infinite looo of loadView, not viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized I had never closed this after the recent interest.

As I remember, @Wolfgang Schreurs is exactly correct. For whatever reason, while experimenting with the code, I had `topLevelViewController` inherit from `rootViewController`.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who may run into the same issue.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same issue and cost a while to figue out.

When self.view doesn't exist, iOS will call loadview/viewdidload and try to create the view. this cause the deadloop. In my case, I didn't call [super loadView] in my loadView, and cause this problem.

See this discussion
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=552520

Comment: The official api doc states the "loadView" method clearly:"Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.".

Comment: @Jagie Can you please elaborate more? I would like to take your advise but adding `[super loadView];` did solve my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Set a breakpoint on `viewDidLoad`, continue a few times, then grab the backtrace and post it.

Also, add `NSLog(@"%@ self is %p", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);` to the beginning of your `viewDidLoad`. It might be that you have created a sort of "infinite mirrors" configuration of nib files;  if the hex number keeps changing, that'll be different instances of your view.

Comment: The GCC backtrace you get should be more than enough to tell you what's causing the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I know it sounds simple but try moving

```
[super viewDidLoad]
```

to the top of your code. I have a feeling that super has to be the first thing u call.

Comment: This is the correct Answer. 

`[super viewDidLoad]` (same with `[super loadView]`, and all the `[super view{Did/Will}{Load/Unload}:animated]` methods) need to go absolutely first in your overridden methods unless you have a known and specific reason for not doing so. Otherwise `self.view` doesn't exist, and calling a method that operates on it has the potential of calling `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`, which is the method you are calling from, thus an infinite circular loop.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the loadView method and it fixed it for me , if you have that method in your .m file delete it!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.view addSubview:topLevelController.view]`

Comment: Got a warning saying "'UIView' may not respond to '-insertSubview:'" and still having the problem.

Comment: He said `-addSubview:`, not `-insertSubview:`. You typoed. ;p

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan
Ugh thank you for pointing that out, I've been staring at this for a little too long I think!

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and look where your loop is running through...

Answer (score 0):

This happens also if you make a `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *loadView` and access it in `viewDidLoad`
You have to rename the property.